# Trouble with calling a function in HTML

Tags: javascript, css

I have been given a set of JavaScript code to create a double countdown event, however I am having trouble to put into the HTML, could someone direct me how to do it?

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function daysLeft(BigDay) {
msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);

return daysLeft;
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<p><script>
daysLeft (new Date("6 August, 2016"));
</script></p>
<p><script>
daysLeft (new Date("6 August, 2017"));
</script></p>
```

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hmktnLo9/
Do it in js and just push result to html.

**js**

```
var id1 = document.getElementById('id1');
var id2 = document.getElementById('id2');

var today = new Date();

function daysLeft(BigDay) {
msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
f_daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);

return f_daysLeft;
}

id1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(daysLeft (new Date("6 August, 2016"))));
id2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(daysLeft (new Date("6 August, 2017"))));
```

**html**

```
<p id="id1"></p>
<p id="id2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a jquery solution if you like?

you have to give id's to the `<p>` tags and then put the values of the function into it. I altert your javascript code because it had no 'today' in it, thats why it did not work. you now first have to add the 'bigday' and after that 'today' or a other date from were you want to count down from.

this is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5Lzv7h8/24/)

html code:

```
<p id="date2016"></p>
<p id="date2017"></p>
```

javascript (jquery) code:

```
function daysLeft(BigDay, today) {
msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);

return daysLeft;
}
todayToBigday = daysLeft(new Date("6 August, 2017"), new Date("3 August,2016"));
/*
todayToBigday = daysLeft(
new Date("6 August, 2017"), //bigdate
new Date("3 August, 2012")  //today or other starting day
);*/

var date2016 = $('#date2016'),
    date2017 = $('#date2017');

date2016.html(todayToBigday + ' days from now');
date2017.html(todayToBigday + ' days from now');
```

Have fun!